# ASP.MVC parent with children model in create view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

For my mvc application I need to create Order object each having a list of OrderLine.

The order has name, id, delivery date, ... 
The order line has product, quatity, ...

How can I do that in the create view. 
I can use javascript to create sublist of items.

But how will MVC serialize the List into its member in the Order object?
Do I need to add something special to that field?
Do you have an article about this?

Thanks a lot, 
Radu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to name the input fields properly inside the form. You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) about how the default model binder expects request parameters to be named in the view. And here's [another one](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx).